# get object from memory by hash code

Tags: java, jvm

### My question is relate to security level of JVM

### How we can we get the object from memory by proving hash code?

Today i was thinking. I create an object of class A in an execution environment One. And get the hash code from here of that object.

### Now in another execution environment i want to get back class A object by providing hash code.

I think it is possible. Because when I execute environment one. Again and again i get that JVM  return the same hash code.

Means it first find the object in its cache. If it get the reference, it just return it.

---

So now back to question,   we have to understand what data is copied when we 
write =.

```
  Object a=new Object();// here as we know reference of new object will be stored in refvar a.
```

Then what in actual is passes through.

If we get what data is passed by =(equal operator). We will able to get the object from memory.

Thanks

Comment: The hash code is returned by calling the `hashCode()` method of your object. If you override the default you can return the same hash code for an object with the same properties. The default implementation (from `Object`) does not guarantee that. The most important things to note however are 1) a hash code does not uniquely identify an object and 2) a hash code does it not way refer to the memory location of an object.

Comment: Bosko I am satisfied with you. But is their any way to get that actual address. Or any native method in java library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How we can we get the object from memory by proving hash code?

You can't without access to the internals of the JVM.  Even then you would need to scan every object in memory.  You would also have the problem than multiple objects with the same hashCode.  BTW:  By default objects don't have a hashCode until you ask for one.

> I think it is possible. Because when I execute environment one. Again and again i get that JVM return the same hash code.

This only works because you are recreating the exact conditions where the hashCode as generated, the slightest changes and you would get different hashCodes.

> Means it first find the object in its cache. If it get the reference, it just return it.

By `it` you mean a cache you would need to maintain, no such cache exists in the JVM.

> So now back to question, we have to understand what data is copied when we write =.
>
> ```
> Object a=new Object();// here as we know reference of new object will be stored in refvar a.
> ```
>
> Then what in actual is passes through.

The reference is passed, like you said.  Nothing else.

Comment: address of which place. Means Heap address, hash code or any other.

Comment: But I think = operator may pass JVM Registers address or CPU Register Address. So pls clerify that on = equal operator

Comment: @D.k.Agrawal `=` is an assignment, not `==` or `equals()`, and this assigns the address of the object to a variable.  This variable might be on the stack or in a register, or it might be eliminated if `a` is not used.

Comment: @D.k.Agrawal The reference can be an index, i.e. not a usable address, for example, a 32-bit JVM can address up to 64 GB of memory using various translations of the index to an address. e.g. `(index * 16) + offset`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is irrelevant since hash code may or may not be related to memory address
take a look [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

in general each JVM has its own memory stack so whether you can access object from other JVM is depending on JVM implementation and I guess it is rarely possible.

Comment: when ever we start execution in JavaTM it creates new execution Environment according to the documentation and a new stack will be created. Than how it is possible as it returns the reference of objects that we have created in our previous run

Comment: what you mean by reference ? if you mean hash code then it is not a reference it may contain some address info  but it is not something that is always true.
the fact that sometimes you get same code is due jvm allocates same space in memory